# Terraform Error object has no exported attribute named "url" in google_cloudfunctions2_function, while using in google_pubsub_subscription

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, google-cloud-functions, terraform-provider-gcp

I'm trying to set up a Google Cloud Functions Gen2 using Terraform and then use the URL attribute of the [google_cloudfunctions2_function](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/cloudfunctions2_function#url) resource in a google_pubsub_subscription resource. But not able to use the attributes of the gen2 function inside another resource (pub/sub in this case)

// cloudfunction.tf file which created the gen2 cloud function

```
resource "google_cloudfunctions2_function" "task_gateway" {
  name        = "task-gateway"
  description = "Accepts tasks created from dispatcher and sends them to the tasks API"
  project     = google_project.gather.project_id
  location    = local.region
  labels      = var.labels

  service_config {
    service_account_email = google_service_account.task_gateway.email
    available_cpu         = 0.583
    available_memory      = "512Mi"
    timeout_seconds       = 300
  }

  build_config {
    runtime     = "nodejs20"
    entry_point = "helloGET"
    source {
      storage_source {
        bucket = google_storage_bucket.gather_staging.name
        object = google_storage_bucket_object.hello_world_zip.name
      }
    }
  }

  lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = all
  }
}
```

The [google_cloudfunctions2_function](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/cloudfunctions2_function#url) resource has an output attribute called URL, which I want to use in another Terraform resource, specifically a google_pubsub_subscription. Here's the code for that:

// pubsub.tf file where I am using this gen2 to function to reference the URL.

```
resource "google_pubsub_subscription" "tasks_gateway_handler" {
  project                 = google_project.gather.project_id
  name                    = "tasks-gateway-handler"
  topic                   = google_pubsub_topic.tasks_gateway.name
  labels                  = var.labels
  ack_deadline_seconds    = 300
  enable_message_ordering = false
  expiration_policy {
    # ttl empty means the subscription will never expire
    ttl = ""
  }

  push_config {
    push_endpoint = google_cloudfunctions2_function.task_gateway.url
    oidc_token {
      service_account_email = google_service_account.task_gateway.email
      audience              = google_cloudfunctions2_function.task_gateway.url
    }
  }

  retry_policy {
    minimum_backoff = "10s"
    maximum_backoff = "600s"
  }
}
```

This code gives me the following error.

```
Error: Unsupported attribute

  on .terraform/<path>/pubsub.tf line 97, in resource "google_pubsub_subscription" "tasks_gateway_handler":
  97:     push_endpoint = google_cloudfunctions2_function.task_gateway.url

This object has no argument, nested block, or exported attribute named "url".
```

The same code worked well for gen1. Can someone please let me know If i am doing anything wrong with the the code please?

Comment: What google provider and version are you using?

Comment: Regarding the question above: In particular, the `url` attribute was only added in version 4.70.0 of the google provider, so if you're running a version prior to that it won't be there.

Comment: The provider version was 4.63.1. So it makes sense to upgrade it. thanks, MatthewSchuchard and Ixop.

Comment: I'm just curious where can I find the supported version in the TF docs? @lxop

Comment: You can get details of any change about the Terraform Google Provider by reading the CHANGELOG [1] in the Github repo.

[1] https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-google/blob/main/CHANGELOG.md#4700-june-20-2023

Comment: I feel like this should be part of terraform documentation regarding that resource itself @ReynaldoAceves. Will we have to see the CHANGELOG every time and find this out before using any resource?

Comment: In an ideal world, we should be using the latest version of a product if expertise and time permit, for troubleshooting purposes it is always a good idea to try to reproduce the same in the latest version so we can confirm a real issue and report it back directly to the developers via Github issues.